# insert,delete,update gridview error

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to insert, delete ,update data in gridview. But I am having errors like this:

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>  
</ItemTemplate>
```

and the **error message is** :

```
 Parser Error Message: The 'Text' property of 'asp:TextBox' does not allow child objects.
```

I don't know why I am getting this error about these lines. Could anyone help about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `asp:TextBox` due to which you are getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have an unclosed asp:TextBox tag. Go back and click on all your asp:TextBox's and VS should highlight matching tags, find the one that doesn't have a a match.